# Send message only to certain client using websockets with Rsocket and Spring Webflux

Tags: websocket, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, rsocket

I am trying to use Rsocket with websocket in one of my POC projects. In my case user login is not required. I would like to send a message only to certain clients when I receive a message from another service. Basically, my flow goes like this.

```
                                  Service A                               Service B   
|--------|    websocket     |------------------|   Queue based comm   |---------------| 
|  Web   |----------------->| Rsocket server   |--------------------->| Another       | 
|        |<-----------------| using Websocket  |<---------------------| service       |
|--------|    websocket     |------------------|   Queue based comm   |---------------|
```

In my case, I am thinking to use a unique id for each connection and each request. Merge both identifiers as correlation id and send the message to **Service B** and when I get the message from **Service B** figure which client it needs to go to and send it. Now I understand I may not need 2 services to do this but I am doing this for a few other reasons. Though I have a rough idea about how to implement other pieces. I am new to the Rsocket concept. Is it possible to send a message to the only certain client by a certain id using Spring Boot Webflux, Rsocket, and websocket?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, I think you have got two options here. The first one is to filter the Flux which comes from `Service B`, the second one is to use `RSocketRequester` and `Map` as @NikolaB described.

**First option:**

```kotlin
data class News(val category: String, val news: String)
data class PrivateNews(val destination: String, val news: News)

class NewsProvider {

    private val duration: Long = 250

    private val externalNewsProcessor = DirectProcessor.create<News>().serialize()
    private val sink = externalNewsProcessor.sink()

    fun allNews(): Flux<News> {
        return Flux
                .merge(
                        carNews(), bikeNews(), cosmeticsNews(),
                        externalNewsProcessor)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
    }

    fun externalNews(): Flux<News> {
        return externalNewsProcessor;
    }

    fun addExternalNews(news: News) {
        sink.next(news);
    }

    fun carNews(): Flux<News> {
        return Flux
                .just("new lambo!!", "amazing ferrari!", "great porsche", "very cool audi RS4 Avant", "Tesla i smarter than you")
                .map { News("CAR", it) }
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                .log()
    }

    fun bikeNews(): Flux<News> {
        return Flux
                .just("specialized enduro still the biggest dream", "giant anthem fast as hell", "gravel long distance test")
                .map { News("BIKE", it) }
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                .log()
    }

    fun cosmeticsNews(): Flux<News> {
        return Flux
                .just("nivea - no one wants to hear about that", "rexona anti-odor test")
                .map { News("COSMETICS", it) }
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                .log()
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sse")
@CrossOrigin("*")
class NewsRestController() {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewsRestController::class.java)

    val newsProvider = NewsProvider()

    @GetMapping(value = ["/news/{category}"], produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
    fun allNewsByCategory(@PathVariable category: String): Flux<News> {
        log.info("hello, getting all news by category: {}!", category)
        return newsProvider
                .allNews()
                .filter { it.category == category }
    }
}
```

The `NewsProvider` class is a simulation of your `Service B`, which should return `Flux<>`. Whenever you call the `addExternalNews` it's going to push the `News` returned by the `allNews` method. In the `NewsRestController` class, we filter the news by category. Open the browser on `localhost:8080/sse/news/CAR` to see only car news.

If you want to use RSocket instead, you can use a method like this:

```kotlin
    @MessageMapping("news.{category}")
    fun allNewsByCategory(@DestinationVariable category: String): Flux<News> {
        log.info("RSocket, getting all news by category: {}!", category)
        return newsProvider
                .allNews()
                .filter { it.category == category }
    }
```

**Second option:**

Let's store the `RSocketRequester` in the `HashMap` (I use vavr.io) with `@ConnectMapping`.

```kotlin
@Controller
class RSocketConnectionController {

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RSocketConnectionController::class.java)

    private var requesterMap: Map<String, RSocketRequester> = HashMap.empty()

    @Synchronized
    private fun getRequesterMap(): Map<String, RSocketRequester> {
        return requesterMap
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun addRequester(rSocketRequester: RSocketRequester, clientId: String) {
        log.info("adding requester {}", clientId)
        requesterMap = requesterMap.put(clientId, rSocketRequester)
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun removeRequester(clientId: String) {
        log.info("removing requester {}", clientId)
        requesterMap = requesterMap.remove(clientId)
    }

    @ConnectMapping("client-id")
    fun onConnect(rSocketRequester: RSocketRequester, clientId: String) {
        val clientIdFixed = clientId.replace("\"", "")  //check serialezer why the add " to strings
//        rSocketRequester.rsocket().dispose()   //to reject connection
        rSocketRequester
                .rsocket()
                .onClose()
                .subscribe(null, null, {
                    log.info("{} just disconnected", clientIdFixed)
                    removeRequester(clientIdFixed)
                })
        addRequester(rSocketRequester, clientIdFixed)
    }

    @MessageMapping("private.news")
    fun privateNews(news: PrivateNews, rSocketRequesterParam: RSocketRequester) {
        getRequesterMap()
                .filterKeys { key -> checkDestination(news, key) }
                .values()
                .forEach { requester -> sendMessage(requester, news) }
    }

    private fun sendMessage(requester: RSocketRequester, news: PrivateNews) {
        requester
                .route("news.${news.news.category}")
                .data(news.news)
                .send()
                .subscribe()
    }

    private fun checkDestination(news: PrivateNews, key: String): Boolean {
        val list = destinations(news)
        return list.contains(key)
    }

    private fun destinations(news: PrivateNews): List<String> {
        return news.destination
                .split(",")
                .map { it.trim() }
    }
}
```

Note that we have to add two things in the `rsocket-js` client: a payload in SETUP frame to provide client-id and register the Responder, to handle messages sent by `RSocketRequester`.

```js
const client = new RSocketClient({
// send/receive JSON objects instead of strings/buffers
serializers: {
  data: JsonSerializer,
  metadata: IdentitySerializer
},
setup: {
  //for connection mapping on server
  payload: {
    data: "provide-unique-client-id-here",
    metadata: String.fromCharCode("client-id".length) + "client-id"
  },
  // ms btw sending keepalive to server
  keepAlive: 60000,

  // ms timeout if no keepalive response
  lifetime: 180000,

  // format of `data`
  dataMimeType: "application/json",

  // format of `metadata`
  metadataMimeType: "message/x.rsocket.routing.v0"
},
responder: responder,
transport
});
```

For more information about that please see this question: [How to handle message sent from server to client with RSocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386600/how-to-handle-message-sent-from-server-to-client-with-rsocket)

Comment: Hi @kojot, I'm wondering if you may have some idea regarding rsocket/webflux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61460983/migrating-existing-spring-websocket-handler-to-use-rsocket

Comment: Thanks I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't yet personally use RSocket with WebSocket transport, but as stated in  RSocket specification underlying transport protocol shouldn't even be important.

One RSocket component is at the same time server and a client. So when browsers connect to your RSocket "server" you can inject the `RSocketRequester` instance which you can then use to send messages to the "client".

You can then add these instances in your local cache (e.g. put them in some globally available `ConcurrentHashMap` with key of your choosing - something from which you'll know/be able to calculate to which clients should the message from Service B be propagated).

Then in the code where you receive message from Service B just fetch all `RSocketRequester` instances from the local cache which match your criteria and send them the message.