# Migrating existing Spring Websocket handler to use rsocket

Tags: spring, rsocket

Suppose I have this simple Websocket handler for chat messages:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
    webSocketSession
            .receive()
            .map(webSocketMessage -> webSocketMessage.getPayloadAsText())
            .map(textMessage -> textMessageToGreeting(textMessage))
            .doOnNext(greeting-> greetingPublisher.push(greeting))
            .subscribe();
    final Flux<WebSocketMessage> message = publisher
            .map(greet -> processGreeting(webSocketSession, greet));
    return webSocketSession.send(message);
}
```

What is needed to be done here in general as  such it will use the *rsocket* protocol?

Comment: Source: http://kojotdev.com/2019/08/spring-webflux-websocket-with-vue-js/

Answer (score 2):

RSocket controller in the Spring WebFlux looks more like a RestController than WebSocketHandler. So the example above is simple like that:

```java
@Controller
public class RSocketController {

    @MessageMapping("say.hello")
    public Mono<String> saHello(String name) {
        return Mono.just("server says hello " + name);
    }
}
```

and this is equivalent to `requestResponse` method.

If this answer doesn't satisfy you, please describe more what you want to achieve.

**EDIT**

If you want to broadcast messages to all clients, they need to subscribe to the same Flux.

```java
public class GreetingPublisher {

    final FluxProcessor processor;
    final FluxSink sink;

    public GreetingPublisher() {
        this.processor = DirectProcessor.<String>create().serialize();
        this.sink = processor.sink();
    }

    public void addGreetings(String greeting) {
        this.sink.next(greeting);
    }

    public Flux<String> greetings() {
        return processor;
    }
}

@Controller
public class GreetingController{

    final GreetingPublisher greetingPublisher = new GreetingPublisher();

    @MessageMapping("greetings.add")
    public void addGreetings(String name) {
        greetingPublisher.addGreetings("Hello, " + name);
    }

    @MessageMapping("greetings")
    public Flux<String> sayHello() {
        return greetingPublisher.greetings();
    }
}
```

Your clients have to call the `greetings` endpoint with the `requestStream` method. Wherever you send the message with the `greetingPublisher.addGreetings()` it's going to be broadcasted to all clients.

Comment: The one in my code broadcast messages to all clients, how can you do that with RSocket?

Comment: What do you mean by "Your clients have to call the greetings endpoint with the requestStream method"?

Comment: Check https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#rsocket and https://rsocket.io/docs/Protocol.html#stream-sequences-and-lifetimes In the `GreetingController` the `greetings` endpoint return Flux, so you need to call it with `requestStream` method. The `greetings.add` returns nothing, by takes a parameter - so it is a `fireAndForget` interaction model.